# Idempotent Keys From Client's Perspective

Tags: rest, http, microservices

Suppose I have an API that calls a downstream service's API called `/charge` (POST). Suppose while doing charge, a timeout happened at the reverse-proxy and I got a `5xx`. But the charge actually happened.

In this case, I would respond with a `5xx` to my consumer. Now, if the consumer calls with the same idempotent key, then his request can succeed as the downstream service would return a cached copy of the response. But if he uses a different idempotent key while calling my API, he would keep getting `409s` as the payment was already charged.

Here's my two questions:

1. How does the client know when to retry with the same idempotentId or initiate a new request altogether?
2. (Augmenting the previous question) How does the UI make the decision to use different idempotent Ids? Does each new request contain a new Id and only the retry logic reuses the same Id?

Basically, I am trying to understand idempotent keys from the client
's perspective.

Answer (score 0):

A timeout should be retried automatically a few times before returning a failure response to the user. Thus if the error is transient, the user wouldn't notice any issue (except possibly a negligible delay in response).

The request originating system should maintain a log of all requests with their status. Thus if the glitch persists for a longer duration, the system can retry failed requests periodically as well as provide a detailed UI view of the submitted requests to the user. This eliminates the need for the user to ever retry a request. The system will do that on user's behalf.